# Zooming image carousel in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a `GuestureDetector` with its child as `Carousel Image` where the image paths are stored in a List. The `onTap` of `GuestureDetector` navigates to another widget `FullScreenView` to zoom-in the current `Carousel Image`. The `FullScreenView` requires the image url as a parameter. How to I pass the url of the current image in screen to the `FullScreenView`.

This is my `GuestureDetector`
:

```
GestureDetector(
        child: picturesUI(),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) {
              return FullPhotoScreen(url: widget.imagesListUrl[i]);
            },
          ));
        },
      ),
```

`picturesUI` which is a `Carousel Image`:

````
Widget picturesUI() {
    return Carousel(
      dotSize: 5,
      dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
      autoplay: false,
      images: [
        AssetImage(
          widget.imagesListUrl[0],
        ),
        AssetImage(
          widget.imagesListUrl[1],
        ),
        AssetImage(
          widget.imagesListUrl[2],
        ),
        AssetImage(
          widget.imagesListUrl[3],
        ),
        AssetImage(
          widget.imagesListUrl[4],
        ),
        AssetImage(
          widget.imagesListUrl[5],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of wrapping `GestureDetector` around picturesUI, you wrap around each Carousel AssetImage. It might be easier to implement. Like this:

```
Widget picturesUI() {
return Carousel(
  dotSize: 5,
  dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
  autoplay: false,
  images: [
    GestureDetector( 
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) {
            return FullPhotoScreen(url: widget.imagesListUrl[0]);
          },
        ));
      },
      child: AssetImage(
        widget.imagesListUrl[0],
      )
    ),
    GestureDetector( 
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) {
            return FullPhotoScreen(url: widget.imagesListUrl[1]);
          },
        ));
      },
      child: AssetImage(
        widget.imagesListUrl[1],
      )
    ),
    GestureDetector( 
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) {
            return FullPhotoScreen(url: widget.imagesListUrl[2]);
          },
        ));
      },
      child: AssetImage(
        widget.imagesListUrl[2],
      )
    ),
    //and so on...
  ],
 );
}
```

Comment: As AssetImage is not a Widget we need to use Image.Asset.